# How can I resolve ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow' problem?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pip

Tensorflow is successfully installed on my laptop.

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.2.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\users\my name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires: protobuf, astunparse, h5py, opt-einsum, wrapt, grpcio, termcolor, gast, tensorflow-estimator, scipy, six, tensorboard, wheel, google-pasta, numpy, keras-preprocessing, absl-py
Required-by:
```

The environment is Windows 8.1, python 3.7.1, pip 20.1.1.

When I run this test file

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant("hello TensorFlow!")
sess=tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

, I get the following error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'.
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: you may have multiple python installations or virtual envs

Comment: I think I have. What should I do?

Comment: What are you using to edit your code? You just have to select the good python env for tensorflow.

Comment: I am using Pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

Just install it with pip:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Check this page:
https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/

Comment: The 1st line of the Q is: "*Tensorflow is successfully installed*"

Comment: I installed with pip.

Comment: If you are using virtualenv, install it out of the virtualenv.

Comment: Tensorflow is installed on Anaconda folder "C:\Users\....\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages", but I should install that on " C:\Users\.....\venv\Lib\site-packages". How can I do this?